# Hackerrank Box It

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge

I decided to solve the [Box It!](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/box-it/copy-from/32041984) challenge in Hackerrank to improve my C++ knowledge as I'm still new to the language.

> Design a class named Box whose dimensions are integers and private to
>   the class. The dimensions are labeled: length \$l\$ , breadth \$b\$ ,
>   and height \$h\$.
>
> The default constructor of the class should initialise \$l\$ ,\$b\$ 
>   ,\$h\$  and  to length, breadth and height .
>
> The parameterized constructor `Box(int length, int breadth, int
>   height)` should initialize Box's \$l\$ , \$b\$ and \$h\$ to length,
>   breadth and height.
>
> The copy constructor `Box(Box B)` should set \$l\$ , \$b\$ and \$h\$
>   to \$B\$ 's  \$l\$ , \$b\$ and \$h\$ respectively.
>
> Apart from the above, the class should have \$4\$ functions:
>
> - `int getLength()` - Return box's length
> - `int getBreadth()` - Return box's breadth
> - `int getHeight()` - Return box's height
> - `long long CalculateVolume()` - Return the volume of the box
>
> Overload the operator  for the class Box. Box \$A \leq \$ Box \$B\$ 
>   if:
>
> - \$ A.l \leq B.l\$
> - \$ A.b \leq B.b\$ and \$ A.l == B.l\$
> - \$ A.h \leq B.h\$ and \$ A.b == B.b\$ and \$ A.l == B.l\$
>
> Overload operator \$<<\$  for the class `Box()`.
>
> If \$B\$ is an object of class Box:
>
> \$cout << B\$ should print  \$ B.l, B.b \$ and \$B.h\$ on a single
>   line separated by spaces.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> \$0 \leq l,b,h \leq 10^5\$ Two boxes being compared using the \$<\$
>   operator will not have all three dimensions equal.

Here is my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;
class Box{

    int length, breadth, height;
    public:
    Box (){
        length =0;
        breadth = 0;
        height =0;
    }
    Box (int l, int b, int h)
    {
        length =l;
        breadth = b;
        height = h;
    }
    Box(const Box& b){
        length =  b.length;
        breadth = b.breadth;
        height =  b.height;

    }
    int getLength(){
        return length;
    }
    int getBreadth (){
        return breadth;
    }
    int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }
    long long CalculateVolume(){
        return (long long) length * breadth * height;
    }

    bool operator<(Box& b){

        if(this->length <= b.length || this->breadth <= b.breadth && this->length == b.length || 

          this->height <= b.height && this->length == b.length && this->breadth == b.breadth)
        {

        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, const Box &B);

};
         ostream& operator<<(ostream  &out, const Box &B){
         out<< B.length<<" "<< B.breadth<< " " << B.height;
         return out;
    }
void check2()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    Box temp;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int type;
        cin>>type;
        if(type ==1)
        {
            cout<<temp<<endl;
        }
        if(type == 2)
        {
            int l,b,h;
            cin>>l>>b>>h;
            Box NewBox(l,b,h);
            temp=NewBox;
            cout<<temp<<endl;
        }
        if(type==3)
        {
            int l,b,h;
            cin>>l>>b>>h;
            Box NewBox(l,b,h);
            if(NewBox<temp)
            {
                cout<<"Lesser\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Greater\n";
            }
        }
        if(type==4)
        {
            cout<<temp.CalculateVolume()<<endl;
        }
        if(type==5)
        {
            Box NewBox(temp);
            cout<<NewBox<<endl;
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    check2();
}
```

**Final thoughts**

- I now I shouldn't be using this line of code `using namespace std;` as recommended in other reviews but Hackerrank had this pre-defined and I couldn't change it. The `Check2()` and `main()` were also predefined as well.
- Was the use of `friend` method an overkill?
- Did I override the operators `<<` and `<` correctly?
- How can I improve this code?

Comment: Just an fyi, you can change any of the code that Hackerrank supplies.  As long as the code will compile, it will accept it.

Comment: You need parenthesis on your operator< otherwise the comparisons are made serially

Comment: @tinstaafl the code is in a locked editor and I'm only meant to write a class that will be called by the locked editor

Comment: OK.  I also noticed the the < operator code only tests < but the description uses <=.

Comment: I must have changed it whilst copying the code to an editor . Good Spot on . I will make amends

Answer (score 1):

- The problem statement defines the *less than* condition differently.
- I recommend to use `tuple<int, int, int>` for box dimensions. The default `operator<` for tuples does exactly what the problem statement asks for.
- The

  ```
  if (condition)
  {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
  ```

  is a long way to say

  ```
  return condition;
  ```
- `this->` is just a noise. You may safely refer to `this->length` as `length`.
- An indentation for `operator<<` is confusing, but I assume it a copy-paste error.
- `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is always wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange to use a *signed* type for length, but that appears to be imposed on you by the problem statement, so blame a poor specification for that.

Despite the letters `std`, `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not a standard header, so you have a portability bug.  Even where it exists, it brings in far more than you need, so get used to including just the headers you need.

Avoid `using namespace std;` - that deprives you of the benefits of namespacing.  If you really can't type `std::` where needed, then import *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*:

```
void check2()
{
    using std::cin;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    //...
}
```

Prefer to use *initialisers* to set members - a good compiler (e.g. `g++ -Weffc++`) can warn when you forget one:

```
Box()
    : Box{0, 0, 0}
{
}

Box(int length, int breadth, int height)
    : length{length},
      breadth{breadth},
      height{height}
{
}
```

We can omit the `Box(const Box&)` constructor, as the compiler-generated one is identical.

Many methods are missing `const` qualifiers:

```
int getLength() const;
int getBreadth () const;
int getHeight() const;
long long CalculateVolume() const;

bool operator<(const Box& b) const;
```

`check2` is a completely meaningless name; choose a name that demonstrates its purpose.  Similarly, what does `temp` mean to the reader?

When reading input, always check the state of the stream afterwards:

```
if (!(std::cin >> l >> b >> h)) {
    // deal with input error here
}
```